# ArrayUtils.contains is returning false for string already present

Tags: java, arrays

Why my OUTPUT is showing NOOOO?

**UserRole.java**

```
public enum UserRole {
    ROLE_X("ROLE_X"), //
    ROLE_Y("ROLE_Y"), //
    ROLE_Z("ROLE_Z"), //
    OTHER_X("OTHER_X"),
    OTHER_Y("OTHER_Y"),
    OTHER_Z("OTHER_Z");


    private final String name;

    private UserRole(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public boolean hasName(String name) {
        return this.name.equals(name);
    }

    public static UserRole[] ROLES = { ROLE_X, ROLE_Y, ROLE_Z };
    public static UserRole[] OTHER = { OTHER_X, OTHER_Y, OTHER_Z };

}
```

**TestCode.java**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

public class TestCode{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String name = "ROLE_X";

        if(ArrayUtils.contains(UserRole.ROLES, name)) {
            System.out.println("---ROLES---");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOOOO");
        }



    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:** NOOOO

Comment: Name in this case is a `String`, not a `UserRole`

Comment: You are not using the `ArrayUtils.contains` correctly.

Comment: then how to check if my string is in enum UserRole.ROLES?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because an `enum` is not a `String`.

You have an array of `enum` instances, but you're searching for a `String`, which will never be `equals()` to an `enum`.

Use:

```
UserRole.valueOf(str)
```

and catch `IllegalArgumentException`, which is thrown when the string doesn't match an instance.

---

Most of your enum class can be deleted:

- you don't need the `name` field at all. Every enum has a `.name()` method that returns the enum instance name as a string
- every enum class has a `.values()` method that returns all instances as an array

Comment: then how to check if my string is in enum UserRole.ROLES?

Comment: I found that I can also use: `if(ArrayUtils.contains(UserRole.values(), UserRole.valueOf(name))) {`. Isn't it more accurate?

Comment: That's the same thing - if it contains it, if won't throw an error. You can also set up a map of the name to the enum.

Comment: See my edited question. I only want to check inside ROLES array but not OTHER array inside my enum class. According to the way you mentioned, I think that it will check for all the arrays in enum?

Comment: Then use `ArrayUtils.contains(UserRole.ROLES, UserRole.valueOf(name))`

Comment: That was it. Thanks.